# Favicon doesn't show up in the browser tab on the index-page (Safari)?

Tags: apache, safari, favicon, browser-tab

I have tried different webservices to generate favicons and respective link- and metatags to include in my html-header. All gives the same error. The favicon shows up in the browser tab on all subpages, but not on my index-page. So if I go to https://example.com/ I won't have a favicon in my browser-tab. But if I go to https://example.com/some-page.php the favicon will show up. It will also show up if I go to https://example.com/? . Seems like an Apache misconfiguration or something? Any idea how to solve this? I have tried cleaning cache and all that stuff...

For the record I'm using Safari 16.3 (18614.4.6.1.6).

This is the generated tags to include in the header:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

And the manifest.json contains:

```
{
 "name": "App",
 "icons": [
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-36x36.png",
   "sizes": "36x36",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "0.75"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-48x48.png",
   "sizes": "48x48",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-72x72.png",
   "sizes": "72x72",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "1.5"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-96x96.png",
   "sizes": "96x96",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "2.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-144x144.png",
   "sizes": "144x144",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "3.0"
  },
  {
   "src": "\/android-icon-192x192.png",
   "sizes": "192x192",
   "type": "image\/png",
   "density": "4.0"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution, this same exact problem for me!

Comment: No I did not find a solution to this. Please let me know if you find something later on.

Comment: Hey, I tried to check my app in an online ipad emulator (browserstack.com) and it worked! So I think it is some caching issue (even though I did clear website data from my ipad)